# Can I handle multiple asserts within a single Python pytest method?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest

I am writing tests with `pytest`, and I ran into a problem: I have a test which testing some variable, and then I perform some heavy calculation, and after that I want to perform another test.

The problem is that if the first `assert` fails, the whole test fails, and `pytest` does not perform the second test.
The code:

```
class TestSomething:
    def tests_method(self, some_variables):
        # Some actions that take a lot of time!
        assert some_var == 1
        # Some actions that take a lot of time!
        assert some_var == 2
```

I'm aware that this test method can be separated into 2 methods, but the performance issue here is crucial.

Is there a way I can run 2 asserts in one method?

Comment: If the first assert fails, does it matter whether the second assert succeeds or not?

Comment: @SimeonVisser Yes, this is another test I perform and I want to know the result of it too.

Comment: Maybe you need a setup function that takes care of that for both the assertions?

Comment: You can use boolean flags that keep track of all asserts, then you can apply and over all values and assert that result

Comment: Unit tests are not the place for heavy compute.  You are better of finding a smaller test case, or mocking the heavy computations (https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html), e.g. replace the heavy computation with fake, preset object/data.

Comment: Have you tried `try` / `except(AssertionError)`?

Comment: A solution may be to combine your tests into class, as available in the current version: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#getstarted

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Usually, I just let the test fail on the first assertion. However, if you really want to do more than one comparison, compare tuples. Here's a simple example:

```
def foo(x):
    return x + 1


def bar(y):
    return y - 1


def test_foo():
    # some expensive calculation                                                                                                                                    
    a = foo(10)

    # another expensive calculation                                                                                                                                 
    b = bar(10)

    assert (a, b) == (10, 9)
```

When I run that with pytest, it shows me both values:

```
$ pytest scratch.py
============================= test session starts =============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.12, pytest-3.0.7, py-1.4.33, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /home/don/workspace/scratch, inifile:
collected 1 items

scratch.py F

================================== FAILURES ===================================
__________________________________ test_foo ___________________________________

def test_foo():
# some expensive calculation
a = foo(10)

# another expensive calculation
b = bar(10)

>       assert (a, b) == (10, 9)
E       assert (11, 9) == (10, 9)
E         At index 0 diff: 11 != 10
E         Use -v to get the full diff

scratch.py:16: AssertionError
========================== 1 failed in 0.02 seconds ===========================
```

I also tried using `and` to combine comparisons, but that doesn't work because of [short circuiting](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-conditions). For example, I tried this assertion:

```
assert a == 10 and b == 9
```

Pytest reported this failure:

```
>       assert a == 10 and b == 9
E       assert (11 == 10)
```

It doesn't report the value of `b` unless you use the `--showlocals` option.